# When i set value of elements in editor template for grid pop up create , posting to controller as null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

in my view there are two grid. when i select a row in first grid, second one is binding according to first one. 
what i want to do is take common parameters from first one, used in second one create template in readonly or disabled inputs. my problem is input elements take parameter from first grid but, dont post to controller.

**Controller Function**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult DonemKursSinifiOlustur([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DonemKursSinifi model,string DonemId, string DersId, string EgitmenId )
{

    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Helper.Islemci.DonemKursSinifiTanimla(model);
    }
    return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

model.DonemId, model.DersId, model.EgitmenId and DonemId, DersId, EgitmenId  come null.

**EditorTemplate View for Grid Create and Update**

```
@model Kurslar.Models.DonemKursSinifi
@using (Html.BeginForm("DonemKursSinifiOlustur","Tanim",FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lütfen Gün ve Saati Belirtiniz:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.Tanim)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Donem :
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.DonemBaslangicBitis)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DonemId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Ders Adı:
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.DersAdi)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DersId)
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Eğitmen
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.EgitmenAdiSoyadi)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DonemId)

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>}
```

First AutoCompleteFor works correctly because take input from user, not before setted.

**and my javaScript code to fill parameters to EditorTemplate **
and it works fine

```
    var grid = $("#donemGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var rows = grid.select();
    alert(rows);
    try {
        var donemID = grid.dataItem(rows).DonemId;
        var dersID = grid.dataItem(rows).DersId;
        var egitmenID = grid.dataItem(rows).EgitmenId;
        var dersAdi = grid.dataItem(rows).DersAdi;
        var egitmenAdiSoyadi= grid.dataItem(rows).EgitmenAdiSoyadi;
        var donemBaslangicBitis = grid.dataItem(rows).DonemBaslangicBitis;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }

    $("#DonemBaslangicBitis").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(donemBaslangicBitis);
    $("#DersAdi").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(dersAdi);
    $("#EgitmenAdiSoyadi").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(egitmenAdiSoyadi);
    $("#DonemId").val(donemID);
    $("#DersId").val(dersID);
    $("#EgitmenId").val(egitmenID);
```

**if needed, my model **

```
public class DonemKursSinifi
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [PersistentProperty(IsAutoIncremented = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public string Tanim { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int DonemId { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int DersId { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int EgitmenId { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int KontenjanSayisi { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int TarifeId { get; set; }

    [PersistentProperty]
    public int IslemNo { get; set; }  // default 1

    public string EgitmenAdiSoyadi { get; set; }

    public string DersAdi { get; set; }

    public string DonemBaslangicBitis { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, probably you have repeated the id in the grid and also have the same name attributes in the same form to do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DersId)
```

mabe you can do somethin like this:

form:

```
@model Kurslar.Models.DonemKursSinifi
@using (Html.BeginForm("DonemKursSinifiOlustur","Tanim", FormMethod.Post, new { id="myform"}))
{
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="Tanim" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="DonemBaslangicBitis" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="DonemId" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="DersAdi" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="DersId" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="EgitmenAdiSoyadi" />
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="DonemId" />
}
```

table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lütfen Gün ve Saati Belirtiniz:</td>
        <td>@Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.Tanim)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Donem :</td>
        <td>@Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.DonemBaslangicBitis) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DonemId)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ders Adı:</td>
        <td>@Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.DersAdi) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DersId)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eğitmen</td>
        <td>@Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.EgitmenAdiSoyadi) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DonemId)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
var 
    grid = $("#donemGrid").data("kendoGrid"),
    rows = grid.select(),
    form = $('#myform');

form.find('input[name="DonemBaslangicBitis"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).DonemBaslangicBitis);
form.find('input[name="DersAdi"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).DersAdi);
form.find('input[name="EgitmenAdiSoyadi"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).EgitmenAdiSoyadi);
form.find('input[name="DonemId"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).DonemId);
form.find('input[name="DersId"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).DersId);
form.find('input[name="EgitmenId"]').val(grid.dataItem(rows).EgitmenId);

form.submit();
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to fill values of AutoCompleteFor's with javascript in parent view when i fill them same problem occurs again

Comment: And also if i delete form.submit(), i can fill inputs which must fill by hand, but parameters not posted to controller. if i dont delete form.submit(), when i click create new button, it immediately starts create operation, i can not even see form